# Read wicket id value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, wicket

So I've a wicket id set in my HTML:

```
<span wicket:id="current_env"></span>
```

Which I need to be able to read in my JavaScript.
What I've tried is using `document.getElementById('current_env')` but this keeps returning `null`.

Is this possible?  If not is there another way to simply pass the id value back to my JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Please use Mihir's answer below

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34637399/3993662)

Below works, but is slow and is *not* a good solution!

---

You can loop over all spans, and look for the span with the desired `wicket:id`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('span')).forEach(v => {
    if (v.getAttribute('wicket:id') == 'current_env') {
        alert(v.innerHTML);
    }
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/az5q5vqq/)</kbd>

Comment: This looks great I'll give it a go in a minute.  What is `v=>` however?

Comment: That's an arrow function, introduced in ecmascirpt 6. It translates to `function(v) {}`

Comment: Excellent works like a charm.  And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Do not use this! It will slow down your app a lot. You need "id", not "wicket:id" after page rendering. getElementById() will work then.

Comment: @martin-g that's correct. It will make it slower, I've learned about wicked after posting this answer. Can you please point your answer xeon48 so that he can unaccept it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting null is because it is wicket:id and not the html "id". To get html id attribute, you need to set markupId by using setMarkupId("currentEnv") in the java code when adding the component. And then use that 'id' value into your javascript.

You can verify this by adding markupId and then view the page resource showing id="currentEnv" in the html element.

Also, you might want to consider calling the javascript from within Wicket java class. That way, you could create reusable component with passing the markupid as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - it sounds great. I haven't tried it yet but I'll certainly experiment when I have time.